# check data that is not in array with 2 value matches

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-7, difference

I have 2 arrays and I want to check those arrays with 2 value matches,
if those 2 value not matches I want to insert into database.

Code I have tried :

```
$data1 = {['reg_no'=>123,'name'=>'John'],['reg_no'=>1234,'name'=>'Lisa']};
$data2 = {['reg_no'=>123,'name'=>'John'],['reg_no'=>1234,'name'=>'Lisa'],['reg_no'=>12345,'name'=>'Roger']};


foreach($data1 as $d1)
  foreach($data2 as $d2)

   if($d1['reg_no'] != $d2['reg_no'] && $d1['name'] != $d2['name'])
       
      //insert into database
      // this not work because it will enter all data that not match

   endif

  endforeach
endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use FirstOrNew Or FirstOrCreate in laravel.
like **insert if not exist**

```
$students = User::firstOrNew(['student_id' => $request->student_id, 'course_code' => $request->course_code]);
$students->foo = $request->foo;
$students->save();
```

Comment: this is not i want, Im asking how to check two arrays with 2 values matches

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data1 = {['reg_no'=>123,'name'=>'John'],['reg_no'=>1234,'name'=>'Lisa']};
    $data2 = {['reg_no'=>123,'name'=>'John'],['reg_no'=>1234,'name'=>'Lisa'],['reg_no'=>12345,'name'=>'Roger']};
    $data = array_uintersect($data1, $data2, "strcasecmp");
if($data['reg_no'] != $data1['reg_no'] && $data2['reg_no']) {
    // insert
}
```

Comment: sorry i got error "strcasecmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"